# What does "20 weeks pregnant" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

First, let us agree that a woman is either pregnant or she is not  I suppose a third state of uncertainty is possible, but that is more of a mental as opposed to a physical state.

Is the phrasing "20 weeks pregnant" legitimate English?  It is used quite frequently, but a reading without context would seem to lead one to believe that it means there are degrees of being pregnant that can be measured in weeks.  I googled it and came up with many examples of this phrasing being used in mainstream media and websites.

I understand the general intent of this phrasing, but is it correct English?  Should it be promoted and used in publications that care about correct use of the English language?  There are alternatives that are more clear, such as "she completed the 20th week of her pregnancy" or "You are in week 21 of your pregnancy."

If it is accepted language (regardless of being "correct"), what does it mean?

Does it mean a woman has completed her 20th week of pregnancy?

Or does it mean that she is currently in her 20th week, or in other words, she is currently on a gestational day somewhere from 141–147?

Comment: It means that the woman has been pregnant for 20 weeks - it is never exact, but usually within a few days.  Why, what did you do?

Comment: I am not sure this even counts a slang?

Comment: It's totally acceptable usage, even moreso than your examples.

Comment: What do you find difficult about this phrase that you think it is incorrect? When would you ever need such a precise differentiation between being currently in the 20th week of pregnancy or having completed the 20th week?  These things are only estimates anyway. Sperm can survive for several days in a woman's body, so the exact moment of conception is rarely known, even if sex only happened once. Full term babies are rarely born exactly on their due date.

Comment: @Mynamite It is a practical matter of huge importance. In several US states 20 weeks is at present the fetal age after which abortion is prohibited, and a bill is about to introduced in the US HR to make it a Federal limit as well.

Comment: @StoneyB: the medical definition of pregnancy weeks is pretty well established. In normal, everyday usage, however, it makes very little difference whether you're talking about the start of the 20th week or the end of it.

Comment: @Martha Fersher. But Trent Franks and the 9th Circuit have put 20 weeks on the front page; and such rational considerations as you introduce go out the window when you let the lawyers stick their noses into the tent.

Comment: For my 5th wife, it meant throwing up every morning.

Comment: @StoneyB: IANAL, as you know. Nor are you. WTF is ELU doing engaging with this question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Neither I think is OP. It's one of those are there degrees of unique things, but with less color.

Comment: The Q is fine alright, except that I see it as both GR and too-localized. There is the obstetrics definition "**Gestational age** is the common term used during pregnancy to describe how far along the pregnancy is. It is measured in weeks, from the first day of the woman's last menstrual cycle to the current date. A **normal pregnancy can range from 38 to 42 weeks.**" (http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/002367.htm) -- ...

Comment: OTOH, *pregnancy* in general English, is understood as "the condition or period of being pregnant: *the first weeks of pregnancy a straightforward pregnancy*" (http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pregnancy)

Comment: No one has found any ambiguity in either definition.

Comment: This question is argumentative and proscriptive ... not constructive.

Comment: Regarding that first sentence: pregnancy is not a binary state. Check the early posts on this blog: http://www.alittlepregnant.com/

Comment: I am a little taken aback by the debate over what the word pregnant means on its own.  I always considered it to mean a woman is carrying a new growing human...embryo, fetus, child, which is what you will find in most dictionaries, or at least the few I've checked.  I don't want to get into the questions of when life begins, but I thought it was accepted that you are pregnant when you are carrying a developing life.  There seem to be strong opinions here that you are more pregnant at eight months than at one.  Is there support for that definition?

Comment: This question starts with an untrue statement. Pregnancy **is** a binary state.  Tracking the development of the fetus in weeks is an entirely different matter.  If I am married for 1 year, I am not saying in any way that I am less married than I will be after 20 years married.  Pregnant is Pregnant, Married is Married.

Answer (score 5):

> First, let us agree that a woman is either pregnant or she is not.

Why would we agree to such a preposterous restriction? There *are* degrees of pregnancy: someone who is 8 months along is much more pregnant than someone who just missed her first period. Partly, this is biology, and partly, it is a basic facet of language: biology because (as anyone who has suffered a miscarriage can tell you) pregnancy is never a sure thing — modern medicine be damned, you can't be sure of the outcome until you're holding a bawling infant; and basic language because life is never black-and-white. Even a term as absolute sounding as "unique" can have graduations, because we don't measure things on a single scale.

Back to the subject at hand, measuring pregnancy in weeks is a standard practice among obstetricians. It means exactly what it sounds like it means: a woman who is 20 weeks pregnant became pregnant 20 weeks ago, more or less. (It's never quite exact, plus they measure from the beginning of your last period, when you manifestly weren't pregnant yet... but anyway.) It is also perfectly correct English, whatever that means.

As for your proposed alternatives ("she completed the 20th week of her pregnancy" etc.), I don't think they're any clearer, and they come across as (a) needlessly wordy, and (b) not terribly natural-sounding.

Comment: 'Pregnant' may be used loosely as a gradable adjective, but the referencing is to a binary situation. As with 'unique'. And there are many authorities who mention the absolute usages; just stressing the looser usages is disingenuous.

Comment: +1. The OP himself puts it most succinctly: "a reading without context would seem to lead one to believe that it means there are degrees of being pregnant that can be measured in weeks". That's a bingo! The phrase suggests that it means there are degrees of being pregnant that can be measured in weeks, because it *does* mean there are degrees of being pregnant that can be measured in weeks, and that in turn is because there *are* degrees of being pregnant that can be measured in weeks. Just like "ten red cars" suggests that it's about ten red cars, this phrase, too, suggests its own meaning.

Comment: "You can't be a little bit pregnant" is a common US saying (at least in business) to say that you need to commit to some policy/activity

Comment: Can you tell me why you state that someone who is 8 months along is much more pregnant than someone early in a pregnancy?  I've always understood the word to mean simply that a woman is carrying a developing human.

Comment: @PatJames: a woman who just missed her first period has very high odds of losing the pregnancy. Those first 3 months or so are prime time for a miscarriage —  there's a reason custom dictates not telling anyone until week 12. And even then, you're not "safe": like I said, you can't be certain that a pregnancy will result in an actual baby until you're holding said baby. To put it another way, a pregnancy isn't life, it's the *possibility* of life. The further along you get, the higher the probability that the possibility will turn into reality.

Comment: @Marthaa thanks for clarifying.  You have an interesting perspective on this question.  I'm still not able to reconcile your definition of the word pregnant with the generally accepted binary definition.  Prior to suffering a miscarriage a woman is pregnant, and is just as pregnant as a woman who is at week 40.  I agree there are varying probabilities of a live birth that increase as time goes by during a pregnancy, but don't see how that makes the state of being pregnant more or less true at different times.

Answer (score 3):

It means that she (the lady in question) has been pregnant for 20 weeks.  It also may mean that she has been keeping it a secret as it is traditional to notify people of officially being pregnant at 12 weeks...

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but no need to be facetious about it :)

Comment: Who said anything about a secret? Someone might say something like, "I didn't have my second [OB/GYN] appointment until I was 20 weeks pregnant." Nothing there implies secrecy.

Answer (score 1):

It means a woman has had a baby inside her for 20 weeks.

Answer (score -1):

> a reading without context would seem to lead one to believe that it
>   means there are degrees of being pregnant that can be measured in
>   weeks.

I think that exactly how it's treated. 9-ish months or 36-ish weeks is full term. It's just a more precise way of slicing the pie than by months.